# Any possibility that I can remove the next line of the code?

Tags: c++

```
...
vector<pair<string,double> > wordsWeight; 
wordsWeight.clear();
...
```

I am reading a project's code and I often found that the author create variables like above: it first declares an empty vector and then immediately call clear() on it. If it is empty, why should clear() do anything useful?

Can I safely remove it and similar statements, or there is some usefulness of it?

Comment: If no code exists between those two lines, the second line is meaningless.

Comment: I wonder if the author of the code did not understand that default-constructors automatically set an object to a valid default state?  Perhaps he came from a C background, where you have to manually initialize a struct after creating it.

Comment: The clear would make sense after a function-local static declaration, but not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is empty, why should clear() do anything useful?

It doesn't.

> Can I safely remove it

Yes.

> and similar statements

Depends on details.